# Buttons cannot be clicked after making the svg preserve its AspectRatio CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm using a svg (inline) as my background. To have the svg preserve its AspectRatio I did some changes to the `<svg>` tag and added a class with some CSS. After I added the CSS none of the buttons on the webpage can be clicked. Any ideas what may be causing this?

If I remove `.my-svg{ ... }` then the buttons works but the svg does not preserve its aspect ratio.

I even tried removing `<div class="bgBody">` but that did not solve the problem either.

```css
.my-svg-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.my-svg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgBody">
  <svg class="my-svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 800 960">
    <g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<button onclick="alert('Hello World!')">Click here</button>
```

Comment: Try add line pointer-events:none to .my-svg.

Comment: try to add `z-index` to buttons. I think `svg` is on top of buttons.